# Bebop 2 camera can not be operated!

Tags: ros, bebop-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could not operate on the "camera_control" topic and used the "joint_states" topic, but I could not do it anymore.
If someone knows how to operate the camera with bebop_autonomy, please teach.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277052/bebop-2-camera-can-not-be-operated!/) by [mi-sa](https://answers.ros.org/users/32829/mi-sa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-12-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-03**:
What do you mean by

> I could not operate on the "camera_control" topic and used the "joint_states" topic, but I could not do it anymore

? Please update your question with what you have tried (i.e. commands and/or source code) and the results.

**Comment by [mi-sa](https://answers.ros.org/users/32829/mi-sa/) on 2017-12-04**:
Thank you for your reply.
The problem has already been solved, so it's okay.
I'm sorry for confusing you.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-04**:
Can you please add as an answer what you did to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rostopic pub /bebop/camera_control geometry_msgs/Twist -r 50 -- '[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, 1.0, 0.0]'

I typed it in the terminal like this, but it worked only a little.
When I changed the numerical value of `angular_y` greatly, the camera moved greatly.

```
rostopic pub /bebop/camera_control geometry_msgs/Twist -r 50 -- '[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, -90.0, 0.0]'
```

By entering like this, the camera turned directly beneath.
I did not understand the operation on the `joint_states` topic.

---

Originally posted by [mi-sa](https://answers.ros.org/users/32829/mi-sa/) with karma: 16 on 2017-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0